# How can I rename Parquet columns in PyArrow without reading the data?

Tags: python, parquet, pyarrow

Is it possible to rename the column name of a Parquet file without having to read the entire table, rename the columns, and then write the table again?

In other words, does PyArrow provide a function to rename column names directly, without having to read and write the data?
For this purpose, I am doing the following:

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

original = pq.read_table('table.parquet')
renamed = original.rename_columns(['a', 'c'])
pq.write_table(renamed, 'renamed.parquet')
```

Comment: No, because of [how a parquet file is structured](https://parquet.apache.org/docs/file-format/). Basically it has to re-write the metadata according to the new column names, this will force it to rewrite the entire file

Comment: What is the purpose of [write_metadata](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_metadata.html) then?

Comment: As the documentation says, to "generate a metadata-only parquet file." That is, a file with no actual data. You can merge this with an existing dataset, but to do so, you'll still have to write a new parquet file

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible.  The only spot that contains column names is the file metadata.  The file metadata is always at the end of the file.  So you would only need to rewrite the file metadata (and, since it is at the end, it is ok to make it longer).

However, no implementation that I am aware of has support for this.  This is most likely because updating existing files is a tricky operation that can easily lead to failure.  Instead, most systems implement schema evolution to support column renames in a dataset (collection of files) without having to change files that have already been written.  For example, [here is a description of how the problem is handled in Iceberg](https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/evolution/).